# How to keep `NSTextView` width constrained while the scrollbar at the edge of superView

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstextview

I have recently started Cocoa programing and stuck at a simple task.

I have `NSTextView` which is inside `NSScrollView`. I have constrained the 
`NSScrollView` to the edges of `NSWindow`. Programatically set inset to

```
self.textView.textContainerInset = NSMakeSize(50 , 20)
```

What I need is to keep `NSTextView` container centrally aligned and width = 400, when app is windowed, resizes or goes to full screen while **keeping** the scroll bar at the edge of window.